# Почему выдает ошибку при попытке создать массив с обращением на БД в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пытаюсь создать массив с именами игроков чтобы вернуть клиенту. Попробовал сделать это так:

```
players = [exec(f'players_info.player_{x+1}') for x in range(players_info.joined_players_quantities)]
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
name 'players_info' is not defined
```

Потом решил вывести это все в отделную функцию чтобы возвращала имя игрока и все заработало:

```
def return_player_name(x, name):
    players = Joined_players.objects.get(room_name= name)
    return exec(f'players.player_{x + 1}')
```

Код views:

```
def join_room(request):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    if Game_rooms.objects.filter(room_name = json_data['name']).exists() and json_data['password'] == Game_rooms.objects.get(room_name = json_data['name']).room_password:
        players_info = Joined_players.objects.get(room_name=json_data['name'])
        if players_info.joined_players_quantities < Game_rooms.objects.get(room_name = json_data['name']).room_settings_player_quantities:
            players_info.joined_players_quantities += 1
            #players = [exec(f'players_info.player_{x+1}') for x in range(players_info.joined_players_quantities)]

            exec(f"players_info.player_{players_info.joined_players_quantities} = json_data['incoming_login']")
            return JsonResponse({'success': True,
                                 'info': 'all good',
                                 'players': [return_player_name(x+1,json_data['name']) for x in range(players_info.joined_players_quantities)]})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'info': 'Room is full'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'info': 'Incorrect name or password'})
```

Код models:

```
class Joined_players(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    joined_players_quantities = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    player_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_7 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_8 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_9 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_10 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_11 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    player_12 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Comment: Странно. `exec` ведь должен возвращать `None`...

Comment: довольно странно вы строите запрос в базу, но еще более странно выглядит модель. а если игроков будет 13? ну и почему вы используете `exec`? эта строчка `exec(f"players_info.player_{players_info.joined_players_quantities} = json_data['incoming_login']")` выглядит бесполезной так как за ней не следует сохранение `players_info` методом `save`

Comment: в вашем случае можно использовать `getattr` и `setattr`

Comment: Спасибо я и вовсе забыл про save) А про колво игроков игра рассчитана на 12 игроков и у меня стоит проверка на текучее колво игроков если их уже 12 то просто вход в комноту не произойдет.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да он `None` возвращает я уже разобрался с этим)

Comment: @5c0rp Я думал над моделью и додумался до токого тк в sqlite3 вроде хранение массивов невозможно. Joined_players соеденена с моделью Game_rooms
   `room_joined_players = models.ForeignKey('joined_players', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в exec. Начиная именно с Python 3 она не меняет локальные переменные. Решил это так:

```
def return_player_name(x, name):
    players = Joined_players.objects.get(room_name=name)
    namespace = {'players': players}
    exec(f'player_name = players.player_{x}', namespace)
    return namespace['player_name']
```

Если хотите прочитать про изменения exec то вот ссылка: https://overcoder.net/q/139658/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-exec-%D0%B2-python-2-%D0%B8-python-3